# TFS2010 Email Alert for projects with similar names

Tags: tfs

I have a scenario that I can't quite get to the bottom of.

I have a project say called "Zoo".  I set a check in alert (using Alerts explorer) to send user A an email.  The details in the filter definition is Field = ServerItem, Operator = Under and Value = $Zoo, the filter expression is:

'Artifacts/Artifact[starts-with(translate(@ServerItem, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), "$/Zoo")]' <> null

I also have another project called "ZooLife" and set a check in alert to send user B an email.

It appears that when an item is checked into "ZooLife" project, both user B AND user A receive an email for this checkin.

Can anyone help how to configure the filters in making sure that alerts are only received for anything checked into the particular project?  Or, is there any specific documentation that explains how the filtering works?

I would like User A only to receive checkin alerts for the "Zoo" project, not the "ZooLife" project.
I have tried changing the alert definition to Field = Folder, Operator = =, and Value = $/ZooLife but then the only checkin alerts User B receives is for changes made at the root level.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: starts-with in the filter expression?  $/ZooLife does start-with $/Zoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan points out above, what you are seeing is expected. Try changing your starts with clause to be $/zoo/. The extra slash should solve your problem.